# turn on/off screen rotation on switch click

Tags: android, rotation, settings

I am working on a settings app and am having issues trying to figure out how to stop screen rotation for a device by switch click. In other words I want to flip a switch in my app and then it turns automatic rotation setting on. Then I want to be able to flip the switch again and then it turns automatic rotation off. Anybody have any ideas on how to do this.

Comment: you can use `setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT)` or landscape. Simply toggle the state.

Comment: It has to be for the phone settings not just the one app. So even if I exit the app it will still automatically switch from portrait to landscape based on the way i'm holding the phone @user2712869